# Проблема с фреймами

Tags: html

Привет всем. Проблемка такая. Как убрать границы фреймов, чтоб их не было видно ни в каком из основных браузеров? А то Safari, Firefox и Chrome их убирают, а IE и Opera показывают! они мне не нужны совсем! код такой:

```
<html>
<head><title>Фрейм какой-то =)</title></head>

<frameset rows="79,*,24" frameborder="0">
<noframes>
<h1 align="center">Приносим свои извинения, но ваш интернет-браузер не поддерживает фреймы. Вы не можете просматривать наш сайт. Рекомендуем вам сменить браузер.</h1>
<h2 align="center">Рекомендуемые браузеры: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Apple Safari</h2>
</noframes>
<frame src="frame1.html" name="frame1" scrolling="no" noresize>
 <frameset cols="203,*" frameborder="0">
  <frame src="frame2.html" name="frame2" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize>
  <frame src="frame3.html" name="frame3" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize>
 </frameset>
<frame src="frame4.html" name="frame4" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Вёрстка фреймами это самое ужастное что только может быть, мой вам совет... Никогда.. никогда не используйте тег <frame> без необходимости... а вообще что бы убрать границу используйте лучше iframe и его свойство frameborder

Answer (score 1):

Установите свойство `border="0"` у фреймсета.

Comment: Насколько я помню у фреймсета нет такого атрибута, а есть атрибут frameborder. но я попробую, спасибо за ответ =)

Comment: Всё верно, нужно писать frameborder="0"

Comment: Эта проблема возникла не впервые у вас:
http://techpatterns.com/forums/about301.html